# Mapped Statements collection already contains value , but I only have one method of the same signature

Tags: java, mybatis

```
<mapper namespace="xyz.ivyxjc.RoleMapper">
   <resultMap id="roleMapper" type="role">
       <id column="id" property="roleName" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>

       <result column="role_name" property="roleName" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
       <result column="note" property="note" typeHandler="xyz.ivyxjc.MyStringTypeHandler"/>
   </resultMap>
</mapper>



@ResultMap(value = "roleMapper")
@Select(value = "select id, role_name as roleName, note from t_role where id=#{id}")
public Role getRole(Long id);
```

But it rises a exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for xyz.ivyxjc.RoleMapper.insertRole
```

If I remove `@ResultMap(value="roleMapper")`, it will be ok.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just considering question title: *only have one method of the same signature*, it suggest, according to the exception message: `Mapped Statements collection already contains value for xyz.ivyxjc.RoleMapper.insertRole`, that in interface `xyz.ivyxjc.RoleMapper` you declare more than one method with name `insertRole`, whatever their parameters and then their signature is different.

If statements had been declared in XML mapper instead of annotations, then, they would have the same id, that's why it cannot work.

The `@Select` and `@ResultMap` seem totally unrelated to the present issue.